# Text won't appear after pong game is won

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

```
function drawEverything(){
    //next line blacks out screen
    colorRect(0,0, canvas.width,canvas.height,'black');
    if(showingWinScreen){
        canvasContext.fillStyle = white;
        if(player1Score >= winningScore){
canvasContext.fillText("Left Player won!",350,200);
        }else if(player2Score >=winningScore){
canvasContext.fillText("Right Player won!",350,200)
            }

        canvasContext.fillText( 'click to continue', 350,500)
        return;
        }

    //this is left player paddle
    colorRect(0,paddle1Y,paddleThick,PADDLE_HEIGHT,'white');

    //this is right player paddle
    colorRect(canvas.width- paddleThick,paddle2Y,paddleThick,PADDLE_HEIGHT,'white');

    //next line draws a ball
    colorCircle(ballX,ballY,10,'white');

    canvasContext.fillText( player1Score, 100,100);
    canvasContext.fillText( player2Score, 700,100)
    }
```

So I'm coding a pong game and i am trying to create it so that once someone wins the game that text is showed to say which player won. However once someone wins the game all I see is a black screen. I think I've narrowed the problem down to this piece of code however I'm not sure what's wrong. Could someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: so, where is `showingWinScreen` set ti true?

Comment: function ballReset(){
 if(player1Score >= winningScore || player2Score >=winningScore){
  showingWinScreen = true
 }
 ballSpeedX=-ballSpeedX;
 ballX = canvas.width/2;
 ballY = canvas.height/2;
}

Comment: fillText - *draws a text string at the specified coordinates, filling the string's characters with the **current foreground color**.* - also, is `white` a variable? do you see any errors in teh console? regarding `canvasContext.fillStyle = white;`

Comment: Yup this was the issue, forgot to put quotation marks around white. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
 canvasContext.fillStyle = white;
```

white should be a string like this:

```
 canvasContext.fillStyle = 'white';
```

See [Examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillStyle) for reference.